# Cannot post to a LinkedIn group via API

Tags: linkedin-api

While posting to a group via LinkedIn API following the "Create a Group Post" example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/integrations/groups/group-posts-and-actions?context=linkedin/compliance/context

I always receive:
"Unpermitted fields present in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/containerEntity]"

Our app is a marketing developer platform partner. I gain w_organization_social, w_member_social, rw_organization_admin, r_liteprofile, r_emailaddress permissions while authorizing.
I can successfully post to an organization page.

How could I fix this error? Do we need to request additional permissions?

Request details:

```
REQUEST: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
COMMON HEADERS
-> X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
-> Authorization: Bearer <...>
-> Accept: application/json
-> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
BODY Content-Type: application/json

Request body:
{
  "author": "url:li:person:<id>",
  "containerEntity": "urn:li:group:<id>",
  "specificContent": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
      "media": [
        {
          "description": {
            "text": "Check out our awesome group!",
            "attributes": []
          },
          "status": "READY",
          "thumbnails": [],
          "title": {
            "text": "Group Post!",
            "attributes": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "shareCommentary": {
        "text": "Some group text",
        "attributes": []
      }
    }
  },
  "visibility": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "CONTAINER"
  },
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at the sample code in your link:

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:person:123ABC", 
    "containerEntity": "urn:li:group:123", 
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED", 
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "description": {
                        "attributes": [], 
                        "text": "Check out our awesome group!"
                    }, 
                    "status": "READY", 
                    "thumbnails": [], 
                    "title": {
                        "attributes": [], 
                        "text": "Group Post!"
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "shareCommentary": {
                "attributes": [], 
                "text": "Some group text"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "CONTAINER"
    }
}
```

I noticed that in the sample code, it’s media:[ ]

But in your code you didn’t use an [ ]
That’s probably why you’re receiving this error message.

Comment: I fixed this without any success. The error is the same. Please note that the error is about "containerEntity" field.

Comment: @AndreyMinogin can you post exactly what your code is? On this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions there is an example error for unpermitted fields, where the user is trying to post an image to an inline comment. It suggests to me that perhaps you’re posting something which isn’t allowed for the destination you’re posting to. Can you remove everything from the post that is optional, and see if the request succeeds? Then we can determine what the unpermitted field is and go from there...

Comment: @AndreyMinogin do this: remove all optional fields till you have a successful request. Then keep adding fields till it breaks again. Then we will know what the culprit is.

Comment: @AndreyMinogin the other problem could be in the containerentity line itself.  Could you share exactly what that looks like?

Comment: I've shared the exact request body I send except for exact id values. I am not allowed to share exact group and member ids here. You could try with your own member and group id.

Comment: @AndreyMinogin I think the error is in your containerEntity line. I would check if in your actual code if there are any unexpected characters or incorrect syntax, or if the manner in which you are specifying the id is incorrect.

Comment: The actual value is: "containerEntity": "urn:li:group:12447845"

Comment: @AndreyMinogin all that comes to mind is that there must be something wrong in that line. A typo maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your full error is the same from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113333/linkedin-api-unpermitted-fields-present-in-request-body-when-trying-to-make-pos) post:

**{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/containerEntity]","status":403}**

403 being a forbidden error, you didn't mention the `r_organization_social` [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/getting-started) for the ugcposts endpoint. You need `w_organization_social, r_organization_social, w_member_social` and your OP only shows 2 of the 3.

A UGC Post can't be sent without containerEntity so you can't just remove that and test, and the formatting you are using looks correct to their docs for V2. Not a LinkedIn partner so can't test and corroborate the error myself, unfortunately, but verify you have all the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using the new protocol X-Restli-Protocol V2, you should try changing any instance of a list "[something,something2]" with "List(something,something2)". Also remember to url-encode (encodeURIComponent() for javascript) any URN you're passing to that list.

Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks, but containerEntity (which the error is about) is not a list.

Comment: After urlencoding containerEntity I still receive the same error: "Unpermitted fields present in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/containerEntity]"