# How do I get enough scopes to post to a linked in group via API

Tags: linkedin-api

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I'd like to be able to post to a group on LinkedIn by using the APIs (I have client id and client secret)

**The issue**

My issue is similar to: [Cannot post to a LinkedIn group via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485165/cannot-post-to-a-linkedin-group-via-api)

However, I only have the w_member_social scope and I tried POST request to /ucgPosts or /Posts (not even sure which is the correct one because on some pages of LinkedIn docs its mentioned that ucg is legacy)

**What I tried**

```
import requests
from linkedin_api.clients.restli.client import RestliClient

CLIENT_ID = 'removed'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'removed'
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth/redirect'

ACCESS_TOKEN = 'removed'

restli_client = RestliClient()

response = restli_client.create(
    resource_path="/ugcPosts",
    entity={
        "author": "urn:li:person:[id-from-url-at-profile-page]",
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "specificContent": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                "shareMediaCategory": "NONE",
                "media": [
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "attributes": [],
                            "text": "Check out our awesome group!"
                        },
                        "status": "READY",
                        "thumbnails": [],
                        "title": {
                            "attributes": [],
                            "text": "Group Post!"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "shareCommentary": {
                    "attributes": [],
                    "text": "Some group text"
                }
            }
        },
        "visibility": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "CONTAINER"
        }
    },
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
)

print(response.response.text) # 3rd error from below
```

I've tried several documentation examples, stackoverflow examples of posting but in every case I end up with either:

- Unpermitted fields present
- Access denied (I'm guessing this happens for the endpoints I don't have scopes for)
- {"message":"ERROR :: /author :: "urn:li:person:[id_here]" does not match urn:li:company:\d+|urn:li:member:\d+\n","status":422}

I'd be grateful if someone could guide me through this and perhaps put me on the right track atleast into solving this issue.

Thank you